`\tcbox` that resizes contents that exceeds height
What I want is effectively a combination of the behaviour of \tcolorbox and \tcbox: a box that tries to expand its width to fit its contents, up to a certain maximum width (like \tcbox), after which it reduces the font sizes until the contents does not spill bellow the bottom of the box.
As a bonus, the font size of the first line of the box (title) should not be reduced by the algorithm.

what have you tried? right now, this is just a do-it-for-me. you might get lucky and a procrastinator finds your question intriguing. but you'd stand a better chance of getting help with an MWE.

note that reducing font size to fit is one of the Typographer's Seven Deadly Sins ....

@cfr The whole point is that I have no idea how to go about this event. Even directions would be welcome, let alone a completion working solution.

your code should set the problem up so people don't have to start a document from scratch.

@cfr There's nothing to set up, truly. Your comment doesn't really make sense, because this is not a "I expected behaviour X but got behaviour Y", it's a question about the best approach to achieve behaviour X (either code or general tips).

by 'problem' I don't mean 'issue' but 'problem statement' in the sense of 'design brief'. please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/231/. (almost) all questions are improved by MWEs, (and likely only a philosopher would add the 'almost'.)
